# Getting Shopping cart quanitity counter to show product added right when selected to add

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Shopping cart quantity counter on my site and it doesn't show the product was added until the page is reloaded or if you go to another page. I am wanting the quantity counter to show the product being added right away. I have this quantity counter on every page. I'm sure something like this can be added with Ajax, but I have no idea how to even start.

I have it set up like this right now:

I have a page a require on every page on my site called loadProducts.php

It holds this:

```
//Shopping Cart Quantity Count

    if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $totalquantity = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
        $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $product['quantity'];
    }


 }
  else {
       $totalquantity = 0;
  }
```

Is there a way I can make this load right after I place something in my cart? My site is buyfarbest.com if you want to see what I mean. If you go to the products tab and then add a product. You have to go to another page after you have added it for that quantity to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can request this data dynamically with javascript using the following.

cartQuantity.php

```
<?php

$totalQuantity = 0;
$success = false; //If session is not set, leave this as false
if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
        $totalquantity += $product['quantity']; //Increment total quantity by product quantity 
    }
    $success = true; //Session is set, and quantity has been incremented
}

header('Content-type: application/json'); //jquery will automatically parse what follows as a json array.  Handy!
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

echo json_encode(array('success'=>$success, 'shopping_cart_quantity'=>$totalQuantity));
```

and in your html:

```
<div id='shoppingCartCounter'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function updateCartCounter() {
        $.get('path/to/cartQuantity.php', function(json) {
            var shoppingCartCounter = $('#shoppingCartCounter'); //Make a local variable to reference the appropriate div
            if(json['success']) { shoppingCartCounter.html(json['shopping_cart_quantity']) } //populate it with the count
            else shoppingCartCounter.html(''); //or erase the number altogether
        });
    }

</script>
```

Now whenever you call `updateCartCounter()`, the counter will do just that.  You can do this either or both of the following ways:

with an interval (not very efficient)

```
setInterval(function(){ updateCartCounter(); }, 10000); //Update the counter every 10 seconds
```

or within your cart operations functions

```
function someCartOperation() { //This is whatever your application uses for adding/removing stuff in the cart
    /*
        Do all your important cart stuff
    */

    updateCartCounter(); //You're done working on the cart, now update the counter
}
```